# should web api content negotiation from xml to json insert @?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have an xml document that I want to return via a web api call.

I want to allow the user the option of the response via content negotiation.

```
 [HttpGet]
 public HttpResponseMessage Get()
 {
      var doc = new XmlDocument();
      doc.LoadXml("<MyExport SomeProperty='Some Value'></MyExport>");

      return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, doc);
  }
```

When I request this an Accept header of application/json I get:

```
{
  "MyExport": {
    "@SomeProperty": "Some Value"
  }
}
```

Is it correct that @ is included in the property name?

If so why?

Comment: No I wasn't expecting it either but first time I have tried something like this and there was nothing obvious about when searching...

Comment: It might be because `SomeProperty` is an attribute and not a nested element. If it's a nested element does it still have `@`? Try `<MyExport><SomeProperty>Some Value</SomeProperty></MyExport>`

Comment: With your suggestion I get {"MyExport":{"SomeProperty":"Some Value"}}