# Web Api 2 Content Negotiation not obeying Accept Header

Tags: json, xml, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, content-negotiation

Following [Darrel Miller's guide](http://bizcoder.com/posting-raw-json-to-web-api) I'm posting raw data to my web api controller and persisting it. The content could be application/xml or application/json.

In the corresponding get method I retrieve the posted content, parsing to either XElement for XML content or JToken for json and returning OK(json) or OK(xml).

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    // obtain parsed JToken or XElement

    return OK(parsedObject);
}
```

The problem is that this doesn't obey the Accept Header, for example returning the original json when Accept is "application/xml". Is this by design or am I missing something?

I'm expecting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596866/should-web-api-content-negotiation-from-xml-to-json-insert) kind of behaviour.

Edit - the Accept header is obeyed if I amend the content passed to the OK method to parsedObject.ToString(), so there seems to be an issue with converting the JToken object to XML.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you didn't remove the XmlSerializer from your formatters list?

Anyway you can always control the formatter that will be used for serialization at response level.

For example:

```
    //forcing xml
    HttpResponseMessage resp = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result, new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
    return resp;
```

You can change the `new XmlMediaTypeFormatter()` with the instance of your current formatter for your actual configuration.

Check [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization) link and [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation) link for more details.

Comment: I haven't removed it, GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters contains System.Net.Http.Formatting.XmlMediaTypeFormatter.

Comment: When an object is not formattable as xml the system will use the default formatter. I guess is not able here to use the xmlformatter or is not capable of recognize it as valid xml. Did you tried forcing it?

Comment: You're right, attempting to use JsonConvert manually fails. + 1 for mentioning that the system uses the default formatter as a fallback. Not sure I like that.